# Set value in new workbook depending on data in source workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code below and what it does is create another Excel document from the information gathered from the initial document (source). So what I want to do now is create a statement that will do some checking for me:

- If column E and F has values, then I want to take F value
- If E is blank I want to take F value
- If F is blank I want to take E value

I want the final value to only display in column `K` in the new workbook.

Keep in mind that column `E` and `F` is in the source document.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If rngData.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub    'No data

    ReDim arrResults(1 To rngData.Rows.Count, 1 To 11)
    strFolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    For Each DataCell In rngData.Cells
        ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
        Select Case (Len(ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text) > 0)
            Case True:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text & ""
            Case Else:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "A").Text & ""
        End Select
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 3) = "animals/type/" & DataCell.Text & "/option/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_co.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/option/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_co2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 6) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 7) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 8) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 9) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "C").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 10) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "D").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 11) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "E").Text & ""
    Next DataCell

    'Add a new sheet
    With Sheets.Add
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Copy .Range("A1")
        .Range("A2").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults
        '.UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit   'Uncomment this line if desired

        'The .Move will move this sheet to its own workook
        .Move

        'Save the workbook, turning off DisplayAlerts will suppress prompt to override existing file
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFolderPath & "destin.xls", xlExcel8
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rngData = Nothing
    Set DataCell = Nothing
    Erase arrResults

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple formula in column K.

```
=IF(F2="", E2, F2)
```

- If both F and E have values, F won't be blank and the result will be F.
- If F is blank, the result will be E.
- If F has a value, the value will be F.
- If both are blank, the value will be blank.

You can set this formula programatically. Here is an example that you can incorporate into your code:

```
Sub FormulaInColumn()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long


    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("K2").Formula = "=IF(F2="""", E2, F2)"
    ws.Range("K2").Copy ws.Range("K3:K" & lastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Head of Catering, keep in mind that i dont have access to the column K until its populated, so i would have to have that in the macro

Comment: I added an example of how to do that.